# Turning line numbering off in the lineno package

Tags: lineno

I would like to find a way to number the lines of a text and add references to specific lines, while at the same time retaining the ability to turn line numbering off. (This is useful when one writes a scientific paper: when submitting to a journal a revised version one often needs to refer to specific lines in order, say, to indicate where a requested revision has been made, but when submitting the final version this is no longer needed, and one thus wants to remove all line numbering.) For this I tried to use the lineno package; it does allow to number lines and to refer to specific lines, but has the drawback that, when line numbering is no longer needed, all `\linelabel{}` commands must seemingly be removed from the text, which is way too cumbersome. E.g., the attached MWE (which simulates a situation in which line numbering is no longer needed) returns an error unless I manually remove the `\linelabel{cons}` command. Any suggestion?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lineno}

%\linenumbers

\nolinenumbers

\begin{document}

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \linelabel{cons}consectetur adipiscing elit.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to line numbers is usually not a very good idea. If your article contains boxes, equations or specially designed section title styles, etc., the numbering might not be very accurate.

However, if you insist on doing this, *e.g.* if your article is in pure text, you may consider changing the color of the line numbers into the background color to make it invisible, for example like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\linenumbers

\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\color{white}}

% \nolinenumbers

\begin{document}

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \linelabel{cons}consectetur adipiscing elit.

See line \ref{cons} on page \pageref{cons}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

More directly, you can even discard the line numbers by redefining `\makeLineNumber` to be empty:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lineno}

\linenumbers
\renewcommand\makeLineNumber{}

\begin{document}

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \linelabel{cons}consectetur adipiscing elit.

See line \ref{cons} on page \pageref{cons}.

\end{document}
```

Personally I'd recommend changing the line numbers into a lighter color, barely noticeable but can still be seen if you look hard enough. In this way there shall be less confusion about the numbering in a page containing unusual elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Concerning the accuracy of line numbering, it is true that it is not 100% accurate, but it is certainly accurate enough for my needs (i.e., pointing peer reviewers to specific portions of the text where a revision has been made). The solution involving \renewcommand\linenumberfont{\color{white}} is, I think, only a partial solution, and anyway likely not acceptable to publishers to whom a manuscript needs to be sent for publishing. The solution involving \renewcommand\makeLineNumber{} instead works very well, thanks!